# how do i switch between sets of images?

Tags: android, image, button

Hi I'd like to create 2 sets of images where one set is displayed if the user selects something from a radio button and the other is displayed if the user selects the other radio button,
In truth I'm an amateur at this and it may not even be radio buttons that I want but its one set of images for a girl and another for a boy, any suggestions welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what I did... its inside an edittext but it shouldnt make any difference :

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/exerciseInputFilter"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="search..."
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drillListSearchImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/exerciseInputFilter"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/search_white" />
```

in the xml for example... frame is also possible...

and in code...

```
SearchImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.drillListSearchImage);
        SearchImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (!filterText.getText().equals(null)) {

                    filterText.setText("");
                    SearchImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.search_white);

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

so just create 1 image view and then on touch do something... 
if you want to use a radio or checkbox its the same principle... on item click... set imageview to whatever you want...

```
rd2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rd1.setChecked(false);

            SearchImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.search_white);
            }
        });
```

for example... does this answer your question?

**Edit**

after reading your comment (which wasnt understandable from your original question)... what you want is just to pass information between activities to do that use this:

Activity A:
create a boolean and a 2 check or radios and

```
 CheckBox maleBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.Male);
    maleBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                        isMale = true;
                        isFemale = false;
                        femaleBox.setChecked(false);
                    }

                }
            });
```

you can do the same for female if you want several radios or checkboxs... then...you pass the information to activity two... like so:

```
intent = new Intent(whateverclass.this, whoeverclass.class);

                intent.putExtra("Gender", isMale);
                startActivity(intent);
```

now you can read it in activity two with:

```
    if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("Gender", false)) {
                // set Images or buttons or what ever...(like i showed you above)
                SetImage1.setImageResource(R.drawable.boy);
                 .
                 .
                 .

            }
```

you can also use bundle to get your variables...

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
```

then just get the boolean...

Comment: I don't think it does I apologise though if I'm wrong, for example activity one asks name and gender activity two asks what they wanna do (multiple activities) (each with a set of images) if its a girl then display image set and if its a boy display different set of images, thank you for your quick reply

Comment: checkout my edit... this covers everything...so in activity on you change on the checkbox or radio click and in activity 2 you pass the info and change on create or whenever...sets of images just see from what ive shown you.. shouldnt be an issue now... ok?

Comment: No idea how to get the Boolean and I noticed you use an if statement but it doesn't use an else which I guess is cause its just one or the other in truth I don't properly understand your answer but im going to put it in and get my head round it thank you very very much @Jony-Y have marked yours as correct

Comment: thank you there actually is something im trying to do but rather than just ask a question and have it answered I want to go away and understand it, as its a much bigger idea. But when I get stuck.... ;-)